# FileIO cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java

I know I am doing something really silly, but it's late in the day and I need this to work simply before I do the actual program out. Getting a FileIO cannot be resolved to a type error, so not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
package lab1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class First {

        public static String[] array;
        public static void main(String[] args){
          File loadFile = new File("first.txt");    

          int nElems = 3;
          array = new String[nElems];
          FileIO myFileIO = new FileIO();
          array = myFileIO.getContents(loadFile, nElems); 


          for(int x = 0; x < nElems - 1; x++) {
                System.out.println(array[x]);   
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: What's `FileIO`? If it's your class in a different package than `lab`, you need to `import` it.

Comment: Unless you created your own FileIO class Java doesn't have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileIO cannot be resolved to a type` is simply that *javac* cannot recognize the `FileIO` word !!

You need to import it. or to write it by yourself.

PS:It is really late go to sleep, check that tomorrow :)

Comment: It might be late for you but for some people across the world, it may be noon

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm an idiot. Forgot to connect the FileIO class to the program. Like I said, it was late :P